# Statement involving subspaces of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ over $F$.
>
> Is $$A \cap (B + C) \subseteq (A \cap B) + (A \cap C)$$ true?

If not, kindly give a counterexample.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong.

Take $$A=\{(x,x)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\in\mathbb{R}\} \text{        }(\text{the line } y=x)$$

$$ B = \{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x\in\mathbb{R}\} \text{   } (\text{the } x-\text{axis})$$
$$ C = \{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y\in\mathbb{R}\} \text{   } (\text{the } y-\text{axis})$$

Then $A\cap B = A\cap C = \{(0,0)\}$ but $B+C=\mathbb{R}^2$ so $A\cap (B+C)=A$.